# PHP - Symfony2 - Passing a url with the request

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with some code originally written by someone else, using the Symfony2 framework to create routes in the form:

```
http://my_site.com/account/add
http://my_site.com/account/delete, etc.
```

The problem is that if I have something like this:

```
http://my_site.com/account/add/{"account_id":"test","web_site":"http://www.another_site.com"}
```

I am urlencoding the JSON string before sending it, but I am getting a 404 (route not found)

if I remove the http:// it works fine

Even if I do something like:

```
http://my_site.com/account/add/{"account_id":"test","web_site":"www.another_site.com/funstuff"}
```

I also get a 404 , with a message about route not found, which I assume comes from the symfony2 framework. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your router look like for this? Any requirements? Typically Resources/config/routing.yml... Passing all that garbage through the url seems crazy anyways...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess here and suggest trying to send the JSON via POST inside the body of the request. I've never seen something that requires putting JSON in a URL.

Comment: +1 for recognizing a RESTful pattern when you see one. I'm in agreement on this.

Comment: Yes, it is a RESTful pattern, but post aside, the framework should be able to handle a get. I don't want to mess with the Router function of the framework (not that I understand it enough to be able to do that at this point). I will try a post

Answer (score 0):

why are you passing as GET and not a POST.  post generally used when data is sent to server causing data on the server to change.